# Automapper: How to handle fields in target object that are not in source object

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I'm observing that if a source object does not contain fields that are in the target object, the target object field is set to null (thus losing the value in that field if there was any).

For ex:
Source Obj:

```
public class SourceObj{
  public int Id {get; set; }
  public string Name {get; set; }
  public string Value1{get; set; }
}
```

Target Object:

```
public class TargetObj{
  public int Id {get; set; }
  public string Name {get; set; }
  public string Value1{get; set; }
  public string Value2{get; set; }
  public string Value3{get; set; }
}
```

If updating a targetObj:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'name1',
  Value1: 'value1',
  Value2: 'value2',
  Value3: 'value3',
}
```

with a sourceObj:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'name1',
  Value1: 'value1Updated'
}
```

using:

```
CreateMap<sourceObj, targetObj>();
```

the targetObj becomes:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'name1',
  Value1: 'value1Updated',
  Value2: null,
  Value3: null,
}
```

I'm trying to get to:

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'name1',
  Value1: 'value1Updated',
  Value2: 'value2',
  Value3: 'value3',
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this, specifically to LEAVE THE TARGET VALUES AS THEY WERE FOR FIELDS NOT IN THE sourceObj?

I've tried the following without success:

```
CreateMap<sourceObj, targetObj>(MemberList.Source);
CreateMap<sourceObj, targetObj>(MemberList.None);
```

Appreciate any help here...

Answer (score 1):

`AutoMapper` does **not** change any properties in target object if they don't exist in source object. Here is a demo to prove that:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHlJKC

Comment: Thanks Dimitris, I'll review my work to see why I made this assumption.